# Vue CLI error: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am facing an issue in my Vue project while trying to render the data from local JSON. I have read instructions and followed them-- every step-- yet the error prevails. Since I am new to Vue and advanced programming itself, I seek help.

**english.json**

```
{
  "0": {
    "text": "This be a square",
    "color": "blue",
    "size": "small"
  },
  "1": {
    "text": "here lies a square",
    "color": "red",
    "size": "medium"
  },
  "2": {
    "text": "Tharr be a squaree",
    "color": "black",
    "size": "large"
  }
}
```

**ExperienceText.vue**

```
<template>
  <article class="content__box" :v-for="data in expJson">
    {{data.text}}
    <h6>{{data.text}}</h6>
    <h3>{{data.color}}</h3>
    <p>{{data.size}}</p>
  </article>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/components/json/english.json";
export default {
  name: "ExperienceText",
  data() {
    return {
      expJson: json
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Error

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
found in

---> <ExperienceText> at src/components/mainComp/subComp/ExperienceText.vue
       <ExperienceSection> at src/components/mainComp/ExperienceSection.vue
         <Experience> at src/components/mainComp/Experience.vue
           <Main> at src/components/Main.vue
             <Container> at src/views/Container.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>

Show 60 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <ExperienceText> at src/components/mainComp/subComp/ExperienceText.vue
       <ExperienceSection> at src/components/mainComp/ExperienceSection.vue
         <Experience> at src/components/mainComp/Experience.vue
           <Main> at src/components/Main.vue
             <Container> at src/views/Container.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

found in

---> <ExperienceText> at src/components/mainComp/subComp/ExperienceText.vue
       <ExperienceSection> at src/components/mainComp/ExperienceSection.vue
         <Experience> at src/components/mainComp/Experience.vue
           <Main> at src/components/Main.vue
             <Container> at src/views/Container.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"db619a62-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/mainComp/subComp/ExperienceText.vue?vue&type=template&id=088f3b1e& (app.js:1089), <anonymous>:15:36)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925)
```

The JSON arrived

[image: Proof of json data reached.]

In my app, the article tag is not visible at all. I am pretty sure it is because the JSON data is not being rendered properly. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Remove the `:` in front of `v-for`

Comment: 2:3   error    The template root disallows 'v-for' directives |

I was returned with this issue. And, hence the compile failed.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Comment: I read the link article it seems ok, not to have `:` before v-for,
But when I do it in my code I get following issues
`2:3   error    The template root disallows 'v-for' directives
                      vue/valid-template-root
  2:3   error    Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives
                      vue/require-v-for-key`

Comment: `
  2:32  error    Parsing error: missing-whitespace-between-attributes
                      vue/no-parsing-error
  2:32  error    Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-attribute-name
                      vue/no-parsing-error
  7:4   warning  Parsing error: Unexpected closing tag "article". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags  prettier/prettier
`
✖ 5 problems (4 errors, 1 warning)

Comment: Please see my answer below, I explain further why that is and what you can do about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `:` from `v-for`, since it's a directive and not a binding.

```html
<article class="content__box" v-for="data in expJson">
```

You also want a `:key` on all `v-for` elements.  Since your data doesn't have a unique identifier, we can use the index:

```html
<article class="content__box" v-for="(data, index) in expJson" :key="index">
```

Additionally, this still gives an error because all components must have [one root element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element) and `v-for` can create potentially multiple root elements.  You can wrap everything in a div:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <article class="content__box" v-for="(data, index) in expJson" :key="index">
      {{data.text}}
      <h6>{{data.text}}</h6>
      <h3>{{data.color}}</h3>
      <p>{{data.size}}</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Since you're new to the site, I will mention that you can accept an answer if you feel it solved your question (no pressure to accept mine if you don't).  You can do that like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Comment: Sure, Thanks Man.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

remove `:` colon from `:v-for`

```js
const yourJson = {
  "0": {
    "text": "This be a square",
    "color": "blue",
    "size": "small"
  },
  "1": {
    "text": "here lies a square",
    "color": "red",
    "size": "medium"
  },
  "2": {
    "text": "Tharr be a squaree",
    "color": "black",
    "size": "large"
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      expJson: yourJson,
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <article class="content__box" v-for="data in expJson" :style="{backgroundColor: data.color}" style="color: white; padding: 10px">
    {{data.text}}
    <h6>{{data.text}}</h6>
    <h3>{{data.color}}</h3>
    <p>{{data.size}}</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Can you please help me with the cli Project syntax, as the implementation I guess are different that linking a vue.js.  I tried adding vue.cli to the tag, but since I am new my reputation isn't enough to create a new tag in stack overflow.

Comment: @AjayaBajracharya, okay. ping me on skype `syed_haroon`